# Can other methods be called after finalize()?

Tags: java, finalize

If I have

```
public class Foo {
    private boolean finalized = false;

    public void foo() {
        if (finalized)
            throw new IllegalStateException("finalize() has been called.");
    }

    @Override public void finalize() {
        super.finalize();
        finalized = true;
    }
}
```

Is it guaranteed, even in the face of multiple threads, assuming only the GC will call `finalize()`, that the `IllegalStateException` will never be thrown?

I know that in the face of a `finalize()` method that causes the object to be not garbage-collectable, the object won't be garbage collected and other methods might be called. But this `finalize()` doesn't do that. Is there still a possibility of `foo()` being called after `finalize()`?

Comment: Did you mean to ask, 'after finalize has been called by the GC?' Otherwise, some idiot could explicitly call it on you.

Comment: @bmargulies Thank you, that is actually what I meant.

Comment: you should keep this method protected as initially defined in Object not public to limit the risk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's entirely possible that a *different* object which had a reference to the instance of `Foo` is being finalized at the same time - and may resurrect the `Foo` object, allowing it to be used after finalization. This is kinda rude, but can certainly happen.

Even without resurrection, another finalizer could call `Foo.foo()` from *its* finalizer:

```
public class Bar {
    private final Foo foo;

    @Override protected void finalize() {
        // The finalizer in foo may already have executed...
        foo.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet mentioned, it's entirely possible for methods to get called while one thread is currently in your finalization process.

To guard against this, you can certainly make the code thread-safe.

```
public class Foo {
    private boolean finalized = false;

    public void foo() {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            if (finalized)
                throw new IllegalStateException("finalize() has been called.");
        }
    }

    @Override public void finalize() {

        synchronized (this)
        {
            super.finalize();
            finalized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: To be extra cautious, I would put the call to super.finalize() in a try/finally block:

```
@Override public void finalize() {

        synchronized (this)
        {
            try
            {
                super.finalize();
            }
            finally
            {
                finalized = true;
            }
        }
    }
```